# How to create and use list, of type "customClass"

Tags: c++, class, list, push-back

I have created a class "Node" to contain a bunch of data.  I am trying to make a list of the same type of this class.  I am having errors in trying to use push_back() or any of the other functions.

error is the following:" 
/home/.../FIFO.cpp|61|error: no matching function for call to ‘std::list >::push_back(Node*&)’|"

```
Node *tempProcess;
list<Node> processList; //list of all processes

tempProcess = new Node(tempArrivInt, tempExecInt);
processList.push_back(tempProcess);
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler error tells you "Couldn't find a push_back function that takes a `Node *` as parameter". This is because your list contains `Node` and not `Node *`, these are not the same types. Use:

```
list<Node *>
```

Answer (score 3):

You create a list of `Node`s, but try to insert a `Node*` (pointer to `Node`), which is what `new` returns.

If you want to use a `list<Node>`, you can write:

```
processList.push_back(Node(tempArrivInt, tempExecInt));
```

If you want to create your `Node` objects with `new`, you'll need to edit the code in the question so that `processList` is a `list<Node*>`. Note that in this case, you will have to manually `delete` your `Node` objects before you remove an element from the list, otherwise you'll get a memory leak.